# Return a value when the element is not present in list using linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following code which would return me a value if it is present in the array "arrayID".

```
string str = arrayID.Single(s => s == ((System.Data.DataRowView)(e.Item.DataItem)).Row["ID"].ToString());
```

The problem I'm facing now is that when the value is not present I get the error

> Sequence contains no matching element

I would like to have an empty string returned incase the value is not present in arrayID.

Kindly let me know how this can be done in linq.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `SingleOrDefault` method is what you're after. If no item exists, it will return the default value (null), so you'll just need another step to convert that to empty:

```
string str = arrayID
    .SingleOrDefault(s => s == ((System.Data.DataRowView)(e.Item.DataItem)).Row["ID"].ToString())
        ?? string.Empty
```

Comment: Good point in sgtz's answer - since a string is a reference type, it gives you null and you can use `??`, but it would be a few extra steps if you were trying to accomplish this with value types. Probably a `Contains`, `Exists`, `Count`, or `IndexOf` call to check if it exists.

Answer (score 4):

Default in *SingleOrDefault* refers to the C# *default* keyword.  So when nothing is found the default of the source value is returned.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwth0h0d.aspx

So just be aware that the default of a value type *will not be null*.

For example:

```
        int[] list = { 1, 3, 7, 13,21};

        int v;
        try {
            v=list.Single(n => n > 15);
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }

        int? v2;
        v2 = list.SingleOrDefault(n => n > 30);
        Console.WriteLine(v2.ToString());
        // output: 0

        int v3;
        v3=list.SingleOrDefault(n => n > 30);            
        Console.WriteLine(v3.ToString());
        // output: 0

        string[] slist = {"a", "b", "c"};
        var v4 = slist.SingleOrDefault(s => s == "z");
        Console.WriteLine(v4==null);
        // output: true     <-- i.e. it is a reference type + it is nullable.
```